# Dynamic port forwarding libssh C

Tags: c#, c++, c, ssh, proxy

I am looking for a solution/way to implement the dynamic port forwarding functions built into ssh (also known as the -D option). I have been reading for the last day, and I can't seem to find a reliable library to aid in this.

I found ssh.net which is a C# library, but its dynamic port forwarding is broken in such a way that its proxy handler does not forward dns requests breaking pretty much everything. I have patched the code to a semi working state, but it is not stable, and really slow.

I am looking into libssh right now and it has port forwarding options, although it does not have a dynamic option which spawns a socks server to use. I assume I would have to do this myself.

If that is so, do I have to have a socks server running on both the client and server, then just use a normal tcpip forwarding tunnel, or what. How would I attempt to implement this.

Overall, I want to find a way to achieve the same effects as the -D option on ssh or what putty does when it creates a tunnel. Any links or general information about this, or even code/library samples would be appreciated.

Other notes: This is for windows, so libraries that are cross platform or windows only will be needed. Also I cant seem to figure out how to compile libssh2 with mingw or cygwin so that library is not usable.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi @randy. did you make it work? I am trying to achieve the same

Answer (score -1):

> I am looking into libssh right now and it has port forwarding options, although it does not
>   have a dynamic option which spawns a socks server to use. I assume I would have to do this > myself.

libssh gives you everything to implement dynamic forwarding using the SSH protocol.

Comment: Would you care to explain the general setup, and forwarding functions that I should use/look into. Does the socks server spawn server side, client side or both? Do I just use a normal TCP forward? Could you expand more on this to help clarify your answer? Thanks.

Comment: According to this image I found on the net, the socks server is only client side, so using libssh, how would one tell the server that it wants to create a dynamic tunnel. Is there a flag I pass at connection to tell it to use the socks protocol to know where to connect?

Comment: You have to implement the socks server. libssh only implements the SSH protocol.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @asn ? Is there any example code we can use?